# Does "a few times" put emphasis on how few times something is or does it just tell a number?

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions

"I've called you a few times, but you haven't picked up or called back."

Does "a few times" put emphasis on how few times something is or is it similar to "a couple of times" which just tells a number?

Answer (score 0):

No, "a few times" means several times, but not many. If you said it without the article "a", it would put emphasis on it being a small number of times:

> "I've called you **few** times."

That is, not many times at all. That can be intensified as "very few".

Here's another example:

> "I have **a few** reasons to go to the store today."

That means that I have some reasons to go, and am considering doing it.

> "I have **few** reasons to go to the store today."

That means that I don't have many reasons, and I am considering not going.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of times is 2 times, while a few times is approximately 3-9. The definition for "a few times" may be different depending on the person you talk to. I refer "a few" as around 5, but with a range of 3-7.

Comment: And "a couple of times" can also mean "a few times" as well. See [this ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1427/does-a-couple-always-mean-two).